# Finding records in Rails (confused over what approach to take)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

A user has many tasks.

In the a tasks controller view, need to show tasks for the user. (one view for various statuses - active,assigned,closed etc)

What's the "right" way for getting a list of the tasks, say for the status = active ?

```
#class method on Task; called from TasksController
Task.find_for_user(current_user, :active)

#instance method on user; called from TasksController
current_user.find_tasks :active (user model instance)

#the "common" way that is used in controllers and in many examples/articles
current_user.tasks.find(:where => :status = :active)  #Note the "where" part here is pseudo-code (not tested it)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the association is how I've been trained to do it. Always worked fine, and lets Rails take care of the SQL without any additional code from me.

So `current_user.tasks.where(:status => :active)`, or you could create a scope.

in `app/models/task.rb`:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :active, :conditions => { :status => :active }
    ...
end
```

and call `current_user.tasks.active` in your controller

also might wanna take a look at [the documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) which contains a lot of other nice tips